# Measure actual height of string

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

How to find the actual height (and width) of string to be rendered? I need to be able to draw text that is x mm high.

It should be easy to calculate the font size needed if I can get the actual text height.

Eg. start with a font size, measure the rendered text and calculate the new font size (new_font_size = old_font_size * wanted_height / measured_height)

I have tried using `Graphics.MeasureString`, but that includes some padding which can get quite big for large sizes.

Comment: `Graphics.MeasureString` and `TextRenderer.MeasureText` are the methods I'm familiar with. Both of them measure the actual size of the text and add some margin. Perhaps the `MeasureText` will give you a more accurate result.

Comment: I need the size without margins.

Comment: The "margins" are not actually margins, they are the space needed by the font to display diacritics and descenders.  Try it on your own last name :)

Comment: Unless the text contains any diacritics or descenders, it shouldn't be included in the size. If I have the text "ABC" and want it 10 mm, I don't want the calculated size to make room for diacritics or descenders.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work to add the text to a GraphicsPath and get the size from the that:

```
public static SizeF GetSize(String text, Font font, StringFormat format)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.SizeInPoints, new PointF(0, 0), format);
    return path.GetBounds().Size;
}
```

Comment: Actually to get correct results you need to add the strings to the path with em-size, not size in points! (To convert make it g.DpiY / 72f.. You control size in mm a tad more math is needed..Also: Dispose of the graphicsPath!

Comment: The function gives an useful size, at least when using millimeter as Unit the size is correct when used like:
Font font = new Font(drawFont.Name, (float)(drawFont.SizeInPoints), drawFont.Style, drawFont.Unit);
gc.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, xpos, ypos, format);